What size of initialization vector (IV) is needed for AES CCM encryption?
What size of initialization vector (IV) is needed for AES encryption? I am using either CCM or GCM modes.
--> for GCM I saw online it's 12 bytes please correct me
--> I couldn't find what is it for CCM

Interesting blog on the matter

The IV/nonce requirements are described in NIST Special Publication 800-38D (GCM) and NIST Special Publication 800-38C (CCM).
For GCM, the IV bit length has to be a multiple of 8 and fulfill the following condition: 1 ≤ len(IV) ≤ 264 − 1. Since not every implementation may support every possible length, the NIST recommendeds choosing a length of 96 bits.
For CCM, the length of the nonce depends on the so-called formatting function which turns the payload, the nonce and the associated data into a sequence of blocks. In appendix A of the linked document, there's an example formatting function which requires the bit length of the nonce to be a multiple of 8 and between 56 and 104. Other implementations may have other requirements.

Yes, for GCM, the optimal IV size is 12-bytes to allow for an internal 4-byte counter value.
CCM combines CTR mode with CBC-MAC for authentication. However, CCM has IV requirements that are distinct from CTR mode encryption. Specifically a CCM IV should be between 7 and 13 bytes, leaving 2-8 bytes for a counter and 1 byte for flags.
A 12 byte random IV would be a reasonable choice, keeping the risk of nonce collisions low while still leaving enough room for the counter to encrypt large messages.

128-bit nonces for CCM seem unusual. Which specification or implementation uses this? I've checked both NIST 800-38C and RFC 3610, and they both have lengths between 7 and 13 bytes (i.e., 104 bits at most).

@Ja1024 you are right - I had incorrectly assumed that CCM had the same IV requirements as CTR mode - edited answer to correct this.
